# onclick Save multiple divs as images into a single zip file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure where to start. I'd like to be able to click a download button (or link) in order to save images of multiple divs into a single zipped file. I've read things regarding canvas, but I'd like to do this with jQuery and a class if possible.

```css
.one {
padding: 50px;
background: tomato;
margin: 10px;
color: white;
}

.two {
padding: 50px;
background: navy;
margin: 10px;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
test test test
</div>

<div class="two">
test test test
</div>

<a href="">Download</a>
```

Comment: You need to send a list of images to a server that will then package the files into a zip and then send that zip file to the client.

Comment: Ok, so what code would be required to do that? Also, I think I'm describing "snapshots" of divs that would then be converted to images.

Comment: you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip to zip files

Comment: oh ok, but how would that tie into the HTML? can you tie it into the code snippit above?

Comment: You would get a list of image, then send an ajax request to your server, with a list of those images, your server would then use the package posted above to load those images into a zip file and send that zip file back to the client.

Comment: So is there a way to write this in HTML/JS? And if so, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You need a server to handle the request, you can choose any server you would like (node, php, asp, etc.). This server would then handle receiving a list of images, then creating a zip to download.

example nodejs server (untested):

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const admzip = require('adm-zip')
const app = express()

app.post('/download', (req, res) => {
  let zip = new admzip()
  let files = JSON.parse(req.body)
  files.forEach(file => { 
    let p = path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/images', path.parse(file).base)
    zip.addFile(p, fs.readFileSync(path).toString())
  })
  res.download(zip.toBuffer())
})

app.listen(8080)
```

To send these files to the server, you would then get a list of images, and send them using ajax such as with fetch.

example client:

```
let images = []
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'))
    .forEach(img => images.push(img.src))

fetch('/download', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(images)
})
```